# How to split/expand a string value into several pandas DataFrame rows?

Tags: pandas

Let's say my DataFrame `df` is created like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"title" : ["Robin Hood", "Madagaskar"],
                  "genres" : ["Action, Adventure", "Family, Animation, Comedy"]},
                 columns=["title", "genres"])
```

and it looks like this:

```
        title                     genres
0  Robin Hood          Action, Adventure
1  Madagaskar  Family, Animation, Comedy
```

Let's assume each movie can have any number of genres. How can I expand the DataFrame into

```
        title      genre
0  Robin Hood     Action
1  Robin Hood  Adventure
2  Madagaskar     Family
3  Madagaskar  Animation
4  Madagaskar     Comedy
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
In [33]: (df.set_index('title')
            ['genres'].str.split(',\s*', expand=True)
            .stack()
            .reset_index(name='genre')
            .drop('level_1',1))
Out[33]:
        title      genre
0  Robin Hood     Action
1  Robin Hood  Adventure
2  Madagaskar     Family
3  Madagaskar  Animation
4  Madagaskar     Comedy
```

PS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/5741205) you can find more generic approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for flattening.

```
splitted = df['genres'].str.split(',\s*')
l = splitted.str.len()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'title': np.repeat(df['title'].values, l),
                     'genres':np.concatenate(splitted.values)}, columns=['title','genres'])
print (df1)
        title      genres
0  Robin Hood      Action
1  Robin Hood   Adventure
2  Madagaskar      Family
3  Madagaskar   Animation
4  Madagaskar      Comedy
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [95]: %%timeit
    ...: splitted = df['genres'].str.split(',\s*')
    ...: l = splitted.str.len()
    ...: 
    ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'title': np.repeat(df['title'].values, l),
    ...:                      'genres':np.concatenate(splitted.values)}, columns=['title','genres'])
    ...: 
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 709 ms per loop

In [96]: %timeit (df.set_index('title')['genres'].str.split(',\s*', expand=True).stack().reset_index(name='genre').drop('level_1',1))
1 loop, best of 3: 750 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [`pandas >= 0.25.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html) we have a native method for this called [**`explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

This method unnests each element in a list to a new row and repeats the other columns.

So first we have to call [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on our string value to split the string to list of elements.

```
>>> df.assign(genres=df['genres'].str.split(', ')).explode('genres')

        title     genres
0  Robin Hood     Action
0  Robin Hood  Adventure
1  Madagaskar     Family
1  Madagaskar  Animation
1  Madagaskar     Comedy
```