# How to return the values If One List Against Another Dataframe (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Product_ID':["55165","80125,30215","55557","92361","32619,28965,20147","88722","82793","70809, 20201","11367"],
          'Product': ["ABC",'FDA','FSD','JGH','TYE','BVC','LKJ','HJD','POI'],
         'Country':['CN','US','GB','AG','MX','CA','DE','CA','SG']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Deal_ID':[70809,88722,82793,20201,55165,30215,11367]})
```

The df and the list (deal_id) are provided above. [image]

I'd like to return the country information and the product_id adding to df2.
I tried to use the join function but Product_ID of df1 is not numeric. Are there any solutions?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @Alex, In this case, the code is there (before the pictures).

Comment: @Alex The code is provided at the top of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571618/how-to-split-expand-a-string-value-into-several-pandas-dataframe-rows

Comment: This is not what I want to do @jac

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a couple of steps:-

#### 1. Flatten your aggregated dataframe

Chain and repeat series as appropriate, remembering to convert from `str` to `int`:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

split = df1['Product_ID'].str.split(',')
lens = split.map(len)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': np.repeat(df1['Country'], lens),
                    'Product': np.repeat(df1['Product'], lens),
                    'Deal_ID': list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(split)))})
```

#### 2. Merge with dataframe containing selected Deal_IDs

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1)

print(df2)

   Deal_ID Country Product
0    70809      CA     HJD
1    88722      CA     BVC
2    82793      DE     LKJ
3    20201      CA     HJD
4    55165      CN     ABC
5    30215      US     FDA
6    11367      SG     POI
```

Comment: Hi @jpp, is there any approach like "contains" function and return the full Product_ID? I don't want the split list. Thx

Comment: @Boomshakalaka, No, there's no "in-built merge" based on "contains". And, if you wrote such a function yourself, it would be messy and inefficient.

Comment: OK. Thank you!!